# What is the equivalent of C#'s System.Drawing.Bitmap  in Java

Tags: c#, java, image

I searched for an equivalent of C#'s bitmap implementation in Java but I couldn't find any. I am looking for the Java equivalent of [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)

Comment: What do you need to do? Could imageIO be something? Never used it myself though...

Answer (score 3):

Try [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).